# Rendering VFP as Excel

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have read the blog [Render VFP in EXCEL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003176&type=1) and I was able to partially achieve my requirement. I Have a wrapper class with say 3 variables. Now when the page is rendered as Excel, results are coming as expected . 3 Variables so 3 Columns got created in excel. **But I need to give Customized names for the columns that are created in excel**. How can I achieve that. As of now column name is coming as blank. pls suggest.

```
public class sample{
  public String var1{get;set;}
  public String var2{get;set;}
  public String var3{get;set;}
}

<apex:page controller="SampleController" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SampleFIleName.xls" cache="true">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!reportExcel}" var="rep">
          Name : <apex:column value="{!rep.var1}"/>  
           <apex:column value="{!rep.var2}"/> 
            <apex:column value="{!rep.var3}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<apex:column>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_column.htm#!) components can have their headers specified with the `headerValue` attribute, or by including an `<apex:facet>` within the element:

```
<apex:column value="{!rep.var1}" headerValue="Column Name" />
```

or

```
<apex:column value="{!rep.var1}">
    <apex:facet name="header">
        Column Name
    </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```